# How to start talking more?

Tags: health

At school I am considered the "nerdy shy kid" who doesn't talk at all. I want to fix this problem and talk more and be more social. I guess I'm afraid that people will judge me and that people won't like me if I talk (cause I got kind of a lisp) and that if I say something wrong then people will think im stupid or something idk. Any help???

Comment: [Interpersonal skills](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com) is a much better place for this question. (BTW I did not downvote).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**just talk!!!** its that simple.  And don't care what others think, if you spend your life always questioning what others will think when you say or do something, then you won't every live your life and you won't be able to accomplish your goals in life.  So why waste time, caring what others will say about you, just do you and don't worry about what anyone will say. Just like the Nike sign: "Just Do It"

Right now your young and for you, your whole world is your school and your family but as you grow up and go to college and on to bigger and better things you will see that stuff you worried about as a kid, won't matter and will be like a joke because you will see that what you thought was important as a kid doesn't matter and all that matters is your true happiness. So if that means expressing your ideas and giving a speech in front of thousands of people even though you might have a lisp, if thats what makes you happy then do it, and don't care how people will react because that doesn't matter. what matters is your happiness.

Plus in realty everyone is so busy with their own problems that goes on in their own lives they don't actually pay attention to other stuff. best example is to check out the book: "how to win friends and influence people" by Dale carnegie. in first chapter he tells you that.  Bro always push for your happiness and to become better. So just talk bro and don't care what the other people in your class reaction is to when you talk.

Comment: Hi Ghostnik11, Welcome to lifehacks.stackexchange.com. You bring up some good points. In practice, it's hard to ignore the anxiety you're experiencing. Winston Churchill is quoted as saying, "When you're going through hell, keep going."